# How to show $IMP(FO)\equiv IMP(IMP(FO))$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am trying to solve exercise 8.5.11 of Finite Model Theory by Ebinghaus and Flum, which asks to show:

$IMP(FO)\equiv IMP(IMP(FO))$

Maybe I have some problems with understanding the definition of $IMP$...
I supposed that if $log$ is some logic, then $log\leq IMP(log)$ by choosing $m=0$ so $IMP(FO)\leq IMP(IMP(FO))$, for the other part I need to show that for each formula in $IMP(IMP(FO))$ there is an equivalent formula in $IMP(FO)$  but I have no idea how...

definitions:

Let $FO$ be the first order logic and $IMP(FO)$ be the logic that allows defining exactly those queries that are expressible in $FO$ using implicitly $FO-$definable queries.

Let $L$ be the language, An $IMP(FO)[L]-$formula $\phi(\overline{x})$ whith free variables among $\overline{x}$ is a tuple:
$(\psi_1(R_1),...,\psi_m(R_m),\psi(\overline{x},R_1,...,Rm))$,

where $m\geq0$,

each $\psi_i(R_i)$ is an $FO[L\cup{R_i}]-$sentence and $\psi(\overline{x},R_1,...,Rm)\in FO[L\cup{R_1,...,R_m}]$ has free variables among $\overline{x}$ and

$\models_{fin} \exists^{=1}X_1\psi_1(X_1)\wedge...\wedge\exists^{=1}X_m\psi_m(X_m)$.

The meaning of $\phi(\overline{x})$ is

$\forall X_1...\forall X_m((\psi_1(X_1)\wedge...\wedge \psi _m (X_m))\rightarrow \forall\overline{x} (\phi (\overline{x})\leftrightarrow \psi(\overline{x},X_1,...,X_m)))$,

i.e.
for any $L-$ structure $A$ and $\overline{a}\in A$,

$A\models \phi [\overline{a}]$ iff $A\models \psi [\overline{a},R_1,...,R_m]$

where $R_i$ is uniquely determined by $A\models \psi_i[R_i]$.